# Plot 3d surface or ploygon in R based on specific combinations of 3 variables

Tags: r, plot, 3d

I'm trying to make a 3D scatterplot with boudaries or zones based on combinations of 3 variables that return certain values. The variables each range between `0:1`, and combine to make an index that ranges from `-1:1` as follows:

```
f(x,y,z) = (x*y)-z
```

I'd like to create a visual representation that will highlight all combinations of variables that return a certain index value. As an example, I can easily show those variables where `index > 0` using `scatterplot3d` (`rgl` would also work):

```
# Create imaginary dataset of 50 observations for each variable
x<-runif(50,0,1)
y<-runif(50,0,1)
z<-runif(50,0,1)

# Create subset where f(x,y,z) > 0
x1<-y1<-z1<-1
for (i in 1:length(x)){ if ((x[i]*y[i])-z[i] > 0) {
x1<-rbind(x1, x[i])
y1<-rbind(y1, y[i])
z1<-rbind(z1, z[i])}
}

s3d<-scatterplot3d(x,y,z) # Plot entire dataset
s3d$points3d(x1,y1,z1,pch=19, col="red") # Highlight subset where f(x,y,z) > 0
```

This gives me the following graph:
[image]

It seems fairly intuitive that there should be an easy way to plot either the surface (extending from top/right/back to bottom/left/front) separating the subset from the rest of the data, or else a volume/3D area within which these plots lie. E.g. my first instinct was to use something like `surface3d`, `persp3d` or `planes3d`. However, all attempts so far have only yielded error messages. Most solutions seem to use some form of `z<-lm(y~x)` but I obviously need something like `q<-func((x*y)-z)` for all values of `x`, `y` and `z` that yield `q > 0`.

I know I could calculate extreme points and use them as vertices for a 3D polygon, but that seems too "manual". It feels like I'm overlooking something fairly simple and obvious. I've looked at many similar questions on Stack but can't seem to find one that fits my particular problem. If I've missed any and this question has been answered already, please do point me in the right direction!

Comment: The first task is to construct a function that maximizes the separation. I don't see that you have attended to that task yet. Sounds like you need statistical help first, and only afterwards need plotting tutoring. But perhaps you just want to have surface that represents the 3-d solution to `(x*y)-z = 0` ?

Comment: @BondedDust This doesn't need to be too statistically rigorous, as it is mainly for presentation/visualisation purposes. So yes, I only want the surface representing the 3D solution as you suggest. It seems intuitive and simple, but I can't figure out how to achieve that. Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a suggestion for an interactive 3D plot that is based on an example from the ["R Graphics Cookbook"](http://www.cookbook-r.com/) by Winston Chang.

```
set.seed(4321)
library(rgl)
interleave <- function(v1,v2) as.vector(rbind(v1,v2))
x <- runif(50)
y <- runif(50)
z <- runif(50)
plot3d(x, y, z, type="s", size=0.6, col=(2+(x*y<z)))
x0 <- y0 <- seq(0, 1, 0.1)
surface3d(x0, y0, outer(x0, y0), alpha=0.4) #plot the surface f(x,y)=x*y
x1 <- x[x * y > z] #select subset that is below the separating surface
y1 <- y[x * y > z]
z1 <- z[x * y > z]
segments3d(interleave(x1, x1), #highlight the distance of the points below the surface
           interleave(y1, y1),
           interleave(x1 * y1, z1), col="red", alpha=0.4)
```

[image]

If you don't like the red lines and only want the surface and the colored points, this will be sufficient:

```
plot3d(x,y,z,type="s",size=0.6,col=(2+(x*y<z)))
x0 <- y0 <- seq(0,1,0.1)
surface3d(x0,y0,outer(x0,y0),alpha=0.4)
```

Does this representation provide the information that you wanted to highlight?

Comment: this worked brilliantly, thanks! It also allowed me to figure out draw similar boundaries for other threshold values. Also, I think you convinced me to get a copy of that book. To really make my day: can I draw a polygon for the bottom or top fields, based on this surface? That would be really useful as well.

Comment: Glad it helped. I assume that you were obtaining error messages because x and y are not equally spaced. The function `surface3d()`requires a regular grid; this is why I introduced `x0` and `y0`. Concerning your additional question: I'd be happy to help, but I'm not sure I understand what kind of polygon you mean. The points are scattered in three dimension, so I assume that you want to project the relevant points on a surface, either the xy-plane or the separating surface. Or do you want to create a 3D polyhedron, like a convex hull of these points?

Comment: I don't know that "polygon" is the correct word. To describe it best, I would like the 3d "integral" of the area below the surface that contains the points of interest. So taking the surface, extending it to the intercepts with the axes and then filling the area underneath. This would allow visual comparison for different boundary lines, e.g. comparing the current one for `f(x,y,z) = 0` with one for `f(x,y,z) = 0.5`. Is it possible to get this "integral" and draw that 3D polygon?

Comment: Thank you, now I think I understand what you mean. Unfortunately, at least at the moment, I don't know how this could be done. If I come up with a solution I'll let you know. Maybe you could post this topic as a new question? I think that this could be justified since it seems to me that, as far as the coding is concerned, the issue you are describing is quite different from the initial problem of separating data points by a surface. Moreover, I trust that the SO community will find a solution, especially if it has more visibility as a new, unanswered question.

Comment: I may follow your advice and re-post as a new question. For now, I'm just really grateful for the assistance you've already provided. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

The first thought was to see if the existing functions within scatterplot3d could handle the problem but I think not:

```
 my.lm <- lm(z ~ I(x) * I(y)+0)
 s3d$plane3d(my.lm, lty.box = "solid", col="red")
```

[image]

`pkg:scatterplot3d` doesn't really have a `surface3d` function so you will need to choose a package that provides that capability; say 'rgl', 'lattice', or 'plot3d'. Any of them should provide the needed facilities.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm still having no luck after spending hours on it last night and this morning. My challenge is to get the model/points for that surface. I've tried `surface3D(a,b,c)` type functions for `rgl` and `plot3D`. What I can't figure out is how to get to `a,b,c` from `x1,x2,x3` (I hope you follow what I mean...?).

Comment: Nope. Afraid I have no idea what a.b.and c might refer to. You are requesting a quadratic surface that depends on x and y.

Comment: Sorry, I ended up creating more confusion (also thanks to a typo). Surface functions follow the form `surface3d(x,y,z)` where `x`, `y` and `z` are matrices for the surfaces. So in my example these would be the values defining the boundaries for x1, y1 and z1 as the points that are of interest to me. However, using `x1`, `y1` and `z1` in the surface functions create errors `Error in rgl.surface...cols < 2` (`rgl`) and `Error in if...resent <- FALSE: argument is of length zero` (`plot3D`). So my problem is I don't know how to go from my `x1`, `y1`, `z1`to the surface function x, y and z matrices